# Perl: Search and Replace

Tags: perl, dictionary, substitution

I'm trying to improve my script in which I hope to match characters in `input.txt` (column 4: `H1`, `2HB`, `CA`, `HB3`) to `dictionary.txt` and replace with appropriate characters from `dictionary.txt` (column 2: `H`, `HB`, `C`, `3HB`). Using `dictionary.txt` as a dictionary:

**input.txt**

```
1  N  22  H1  MET
1  H  32 2HB  MET
1  C  40  CA  MET
2  H  35  HB3 ASP
```

**dictionary.txt**

```
MET  H   H1
MET  HB 2HB
MET  C   CA
ASP 3HB  HB3
```

**output**

```
1  N  22  H  MET
1  H  32  HB MET
1  C  40  C  MET
2  H  35 3HB ASP
```

I'm trying to approach this by first matching the word in `input.txt` (MET) and `dictionary.txt` (MET) and then performing the substitution. This is what I've written so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %dictionary;

open my $dic_fh, '<', 'dictionary.txt' or die "Can't open file: $!";

while (my $ref = <$dic_fh>) {
    chomp $ref;
    my @columns  = split(/\t/, $ref);
    my $res_name = $columns[0];
    my $ref_nuc  = $columns[1];
    $dictionary{$res_name} = {$ref_nuc};

    open my $in_fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die "Can't open file: $!";

    while (my $line = <$in_fh>) {
        chomp $line;
        my @columns = split(/\t/, $line);
        my @name = $columns[3];
        if (my $name eq $res_name) {
            my $line = $_;
            foreach my $res_name (keys %dictionary) {
                $line =~ s/$name/$dictionary{$ref_nuc}/;
            }
            print $line;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to have two different `my $line` declarations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are assigning the single field `$columns[3]` to array `@name`, and then expecting to find it in `$name`, which is a separate variable altogether. You even declare `$name` at the point of the comparison

You are also executing the statement

```
$line =~ s/$name/$dictionary{$ref_nuc}/;
```

once for each key in the hash. That is unnecessary: it needs to be done only once. It is also better to change the value of `$columns[3]` to `$dictionary{$columns[3]}` instead of doing a search and replace on the whole line, as the target string may appear in other columns that you don't want to modify

It is very simple to do by building a dictionary hash and replacing the fourth field of the input file with its dictionary lookup

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

open my $fh, '<', 'dictionary.txt';
my %dict;
while ( <$fh> ) {
  my ($k, $v) = (split)[2,1];
  $dict{$k} = $v;
}

open $fh, '<', 'input.txt';
while ( <$fh> ) {
  my @fields = split;
  $fields[3] = $dict{$fields[3]};
  say join "\t", @fields;
}
```

**output**

```
1   N   22  H   MET
1   H   32  HB  MET
1   C   40  C   MET
2   H   35  3HB ASP
```